# Rewrite Rules for firebase.json to configure firebase hosting

Tags: javascript, firebase, .htaccess, url-rewriting, firebase-hosting

I am developing a web app and hosted all files on Firebase Hosting.

As of now my page URL looks like

```
mydomain.com/user/index.html?user=username
```

but when I enter

```
mydomain.com/username
```

It should behave same. What should be the rules?

I tried this but not working

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "psNew4",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "redirects": [ {
    "source": "/user/index.html?user=:username", // username is dynamic
    "destination": "https://example.com/:username",
    "type": 301
  }]
  }
}
```

PS: `username` is dynamic

Is there any solution for this or not?

Comment: Have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects

Comment: Yes, I saw that already, but I can not able to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Firebase documentation on [capturing URL segments for redirects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#capture_url_segments_for_redirects) you're looking for something like this:

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  "redirects": [ {
    "source": "/user/index.html?user=:username",
    "destination": "https://example.com/:username",
    "type": 301
  }]
}
```

Comment: Can you check this why it is not working? @Frank van Puffelen